# left click a ListViewItem to select it, the previous selected ListViewItem is not unselected

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

The Code is my ListView, sometimes, when I click a ListViewItem with the mouse left button, the previous selected ListViewItem is still selected. This scenario is random. Anyone can help?

My ListView:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TestsList}"                 
                  x:Name="TestsListView"
                  Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}"                  
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}" />
```

ListViewStyle:

```
  <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
```

ListViewItemStyle:

```
 <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="ins:MouseDoubleClick.Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenCommand,ElementName=TestsListView}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>       
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>       
        <Setter Property = "Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name= "ItemBorder" Margin="0,0,0,5" BorderThickness="0" Height="92">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/Item.png"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock  x:Name="NameTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Name}"  FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0,5,10,2"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="10,2,10,2"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,10,2">
                                <Image Source="../Images/Prompt.png" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                                <Image Source="../Images/Warning.png" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                                <Run Text="{Binding DataContext.VersionText,ElementName=TestsListView}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Version}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="0,0,10,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap">
                                <Run Text="{Binding DataContext.AuthorsText,ElementName=TestsListView}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                <Run Text="{Binding Authors}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" Padding="0,0,10,5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ListViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/Selected.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="NameTextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="#0261A5"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Assuming that the data type of `TestsList` is `List<Test>`: does your code-behind or ViewModel modify the `Test.IsSelected` property or does it just read that property? If it modifies the property, then your code might mistakenly set `Test.IsSelected`  to `true` for the previous list view item.

Comment: I've checked all the code behind an viewmodel, I didn't change IsSelected property manually. Thanks.